# Obtaining a runtime of the algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I encounter the question in *Cracking the Coding Interview* book (page 201), but its solution doesn't make enough sense. So we have the following string compression algorithm:

```
String compressBad(String str)
{ 
  String compressedString = "";
  int countConsecutive = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++)
  {
    countConsecutive++;

    if (i + 1 >= str.length() || str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1))
    {
      compressedString += "" + str.charAt(i) +  countConsecutive;
      countConsecutive = 0;
    }
  }
    return compressedString.length() < str.length() ? compressedString : str;
}
```

The runtime of this algorithms is claimed as O(p + k²) (p is a string size, k is a number of character sequences). Why it has "+k²" ?

Comment: String concatenation (using `+` or `+=`)  is linear, so doing that in a linear loop makes it quadratic.

Comment: Note that you are missing a `}` before the return.

Comment: Yes, you might want to use StringBuilder to make it more efficient. `+=` is quadratic because it creates an entirely new string and adds it to the String pool.

Comment: @vivek_23 the concatenated string is *not* added to the string pool. The only time runtime-created strings are added to the pool is if you invoke `intern()`.

Comment: (it's also a bad algorithm for other reasons, for example that it is ambiguous: does `6789` encode 7 6s then 9 8s, or 789 6s?)

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the correction. I assume using an intern() would be useful in this scenario?

Comment: @vivek_23 using intern is basically never useful.

Answer (score 1):

Operators `+` and `+=` for Strings are implemented by allocating a new memory chunk, then copying both string to that new chunk.

For example something like

```
String s3 = s1 + s2; // s1, s2 are Strings
```

Is implemented under the hood by allocating new memory of `s1`'s size + `s2`'s size, then copying `s1` to it, then `s2`.

Complexity wise this is linear to the size of the strings.

And as you can see can be wasteful and slow, and for that reason it should usually be avoided when concatenating multiple strings (in a loop for example).